# Identify SMD voltage regulator with top marking: V1TF

Tags: voltage-regulator, identification

I've a circuit powered by a 3.3 V regulator. The regulator is a SMD one, with this logo and code on its surface:

[image: Drawing of top marking and logo]

footprint is SOT23-3 or very similar.

I need to know the valid range of incoming voltage. Unfortunately, I do not find any information about the V1TF marking code nor recognize the logo.

Any hint about how to continue?

The pinout is:

[image]

where Vout is 3.3v.

Comment: Clues come from the parts attached to it, the package type, taking measurements , estimating power load and the reason why you need this.

Comment: pasaba por aqui - Hi, I changed this to an on-topic *identification* question, since asking for datasheets is often not well-received by the community - similar questions have been voted closed. You need to identify the device anyway, so start with that, as identifying the device will make finding the datasheet easier. However if you strongly disagree with that approach, you can rollback my edit. Thanks.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75: SOT23-3 or similar; no idea about max power it supports; need datasheet to know valid incoming voltage to use it with different power supply than current one.

Comment: Can you provide a photo, measure the size and trace out the schematic around the component?

Comment: @pasabaporaqui - Sorry, I wasn't clear. I mean that *someone* has to identify the device (I know that you have not been able to do it), before anyone can find its datasheet. That is why the step "identify device" comes before "find datasheet". As I said, if you disagree with my suggestion of making this a clear *identification* question, you can rollback my edit. (I have seen that logo on a voltage regulator. I can't think of the manufacturer at the moment, but hopefully someone else will identify it.)

Comment: @winny: is a SOT23-3:  https://toshiba.semicon-storage.com/content/dam/toshiba-ss-v2/master/en/semiconductor/design-development/package-detail/Pkg_pkgdim/SOT23_pkgdim.gif

Comment: Edit that into the question. Photo and schematic please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A manufacturer with a matching logo is **Nanjing Micro One**. (Here's a link showing their [logo](https://lcsc.com/brand-detail/250.html) on LCSC.)

Updated:

Further investigation shows that your device with top marking **V1TF** is the Nanjing Micro One [ME6209A33M3G](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/1811081822_MICRONE-Nanjing-Micro-One-Elec-ME6209A33M3G_C83508.pdf) 3.3 V LDO, which has a maximum input voltage listed in its datasheet (both maximum operational and absolute maximum) of 18 V. The top code is **V1xx** where the xx varies (e.g. batch number / manufacturing date or similar) and V1 is the device identifier.

Explanation:

After the OP managed to find a photo from an [AliExpress seller](https://es.aliexpress.com/item/4001149465949.html) claiming to show the Nanjing Micro One ME6209A33M3G LDO with top code **V1RC** (though no manufacturer's logo), I found others claiming to sell the same device with the correct logo and these top codes:

- **V1RC** [here](https://www.ebay.com/itm/264945716261)

[image: device with top code V1RC]

- **V1SE** [here](https://detail.1688.com/offer/586555019466.html)

[image: device with top code V1SE]

- **V1Q1** [here](https://www.taobao.com/list/item/568323225346.htm)

[image: device with top code V1Q1]

and this seller even says in Chinese, that the top code **starts with V1**

[image: Chinese text stating that device top code starts with V1]

Comment: Thanks a lot, very useful. Tomorrow I will continue this research line.

Comment: One step more: https://es.aliexpress.com/item/4001149465949.html

Comment: @pasabaporaqui - Well done, I think you found it! That one shows **V1RC** and the seller says it's the ME6209A33M3G. I then searched for that Nanjing Micro One part number, and see other photos with top code starting **V1** e.g. zoom in [here](https://lcsc.com/product-detail/Low-Dropout-Regulators-LDO_MICRONE-Nanjing-Micro-One-Elec-ME6209A33M3G_C83508.html) and see it is marked **V1QH**. So it seems very likely that this LDO is marked **V1xx** where xx will encode batch number / manufacturing date - this is a very common approach. I searched for V1 and LDO, but didn't find those photos.

Comment: @pasabaporaqui - Here are more photos confirming that the ME6209A33M3G is marked **V1xx** where the xx varies: **V1RC** [here](https://www.ebay.com/itm/264945716261); **V1RK** [here](https://aliradar.com/item/4000411989188); **V1SE** [here](https://detail.1688.com/offer/586555019466.html) - and **[this one](https://www.taobao.com/list/item/568323225346.htm)** even says, in Chinese, that the top code *starts* with **V1**. So I am convinced your device is the [ME6209A33M3G](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/1811081822_MICRONE-Nanjing-Micro-One-Elec-ME6209A33M3G_C83508.pdf). I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Good news for my target, I have some PIR sensors (3.3v) powered by this IC and distributed across a square of 40x40m. I want to power all them from a single DC 12v line. Taken into account copper resistance, consumption and distance to main power supply, I expect each device will receive from 12v to 7v. That agrees with this IC specs.

Comment: @pasabaporaqui - Hi, I don't know if it is relevant in your project, but as I guess you have some long cables then, FYI, please note the phenomenon described on page 4 of the [ME6209A33M3G datasheet](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/1811081822_MICRONE-Nanjing-Micro-One-Elec-ME6209A33M3G_C83508.pdf) under the heading "Precautions" and described in more detail with oscilloscope traces on the Pololu site, regarding [LC ringing leading to voltage spikes](https://www.pololu.com/docs/0J16/all), Connecting a long cable to an already-energized 12 V supply, could exceed the LDO's 18 V abs max input.

Comment: Thanks for the warning, I will keep it in mind.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest many of these choices for an LDO 3.3V will be suitable for replacement.

https://www.mouser.com/Semiconductors/Power-Management-ICs/Voltage-Regulators-Voltage-Controllers/LDO-Voltage-Regulators/_/N-5cgac?P=1z0wa2eZ1z0z5la

Comment: Thanks for your answer. At this moment I do not know if current regulator matchs my needs (this is the reason I need to identify it). If not, I will replace it as you say.

Answer (score 0):

The closest I can appear to come is the [RAA214401](https://www.renesas.com/us/en/document/dst/raa214401-datasheet?r=1490421) from Renesas.  The logo appears similar to what you've drawn as well but as winny has requested in the comments it would be more helpful if you could post an actual photo of the IC in question and if you happen to know what pins perform what function (i.e. GND, V+, Vin) which is something you should be able to easily accomplish with a DMM even if you don't have a schematic of what you're looking at.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Pinout has been added to the question.